# If G is isomorphic to the external product of two subgroups then they are complimenta

Tags: group-theory

Hi: if a group G has two normal subgroups such that their product is G and their intersection is trivial, then G is isomorphic to their external  direct product, as is easy to prove. The inverse assertion however is difficult to prove or, perhaps it's false. To make things easy let's make G abelian. Is it true that if A and B are subgroups of G such that G is isomorphic to their external product then A is a complement of B?

EDIT: 
[url=Here]https://sabercathost.com/Ncr/Rotman_Introduction_to_the_theory_of_groups.pdf[/url]

Rotman, Introduction to the Theory of groups, 4th edition, lemma 10.4.

EDIT EDIT: Sorry, one has to register in order to read the book. I tried to paste a photo of the book page, a thing I've done many times in another fora, by giving a URL provided to me by photobucket, but somehow it doesn't work here. Well, here is the lemma and some definitions previous to the lemma:

Definition. Let K be a possibly infinite set and let {A_k: k belongs to K} a family of groups indexed by K. The direct product (or complete direct sum or strong direct sum), denoted by [here a capital pi meaniing the product over the k in K of the  A_k], is the group whose elements are all "vectors" (a_k) in the cartesian product of the A_k and whose operation is

(a_k) + (b_k) = (a_k + b_k).

The direct sum (or weak direct sum), denoted by [here a capital sigma, sum over the k in K of the A_k], is the subgroup of that defined above consisting of all tbose elements (a_k) for which there are only finitely many k with a_k different from zero.

[Here (A) means subgroup generated by the set  A]

Lemma 10.4 Let {A_k: k in K} be a family of subgroups of a group G. The followint statements are equivalent.
(i) G isomorphic to the weak direct sum over the k in K of the  A_k.

(ii) Every g in G has a unique expression of the form
g = weak direct sum over the k in K of the a_k,
where a_k in A_k, the k are distinct, and a_k != 0 for only finitely many k.

(iii) G = (union over the k in K of the A_k) and, for each j in K, A_j intersection (union over the k != j of the A_k) = 0.

Proof: Routine [sic].

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not true. For instance, $\Bbb Z\times \Bbb Z$ has the two subgroups $A = \langle (1, 0)\rangle$ and $B = \langle (2, 0)\rangle$. These two clearly aren't complements of one another, yet $\Bbb Z\times \Bbb Z\cong A\times B$.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this: as far as I can see, $\;B\le A\;$ ...am I missing something? Besides this, for me *external direct product* is just the cartesian product of two groups, whereas the internal direct product is the same **but** when we see both groups as *subgroups* of a larger group and then it must be that they both are normal in the larger one, their intersections is trivial and etc.

Comment: @DonAntonio I answered the question that was asked, namely "Is it true that if $A$ and $B$ are subgroups of $G$ such that $G$ is isomorphic to their external product then $A$ is a [complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(group_theory)) of $B$?" with a negative and a counterexample. I don't see what's unclear about that. Can you please clarify?

Comment: @Ar First, I can see how $\;A,B\;$ can possible generate their own direct product as their intersection contains, at least, $\;B\;$ itself, and even less: why that "direct product" is isomorphic with the (abelian free group of rank two) $\;\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z\;$ ....Perhaps I'm missing something in the definition you people are assuming of "external direct product" ...

Comment: @DonAntonio $A$ is a group, and $B$ is a group, and they're both isomorphic to $\Bbb Z$. Therefore their product (where I interpret "external" as meaning that the product is _not_ over $G$, in the category theoretical sense) is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z\times \Bbb Z$.

Comment: @Ar Fine...yet I'm not sure whether is standard use and the tag here is "group theory". As far as I am aware, the difference between external and internal direct products is what I wrote in my first comment, and thus in this case it **must** be always internal...but of course this doesn't fit the OP's question as he thinks, and apparently also you, that there can be some *external product* with **subgroups of a group** ...

Comment: @DonAntonio It clearly exists, since any subgroup is a group, and you can take the products of groups. How useful and conventional it is as a construction is a debate for another day. I will let the OP be the final judge on whether this was what he really meant, though.

Comment: @Ar I think I get your point in this, though as you say: it doesn't seem to be very useful...with special care given to te word "seem". In this case, I think your example is pretty clear contradiction to what the OP means...if this is what he meant.

Comment: you can also take this similar example: $A=\langle (1,0)\rangle $ and $B=\langle (0,2)\rangle$. so their intersection is trivial, their direct product is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}$, but their inner sum is not the whole group

Answer (score -1):

take $G=\Bbb R\times \Bbb R$ ;$ A=\{(r,0):r\in \Bbb R\}$ and $B=\{(r,r):r\in \Bbb R\}$

Comment: So what if $G$ is direct product of $A,B$ then $A\cap B$ has to be $\{e\}$ .OP asked whether A has to complement of B or not

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't come across the term "complement" in group theory before, I assumed it meant something other than it did. Still, in your case, $A$ is indeed a complement of $B$, which means that it's not a counterexample. OP's statement either needs to be proven by a proof, or disproven by counterexample. It can't be proven by an example as you have here.

Comment: [URL=http://s1249.photobucket.com/user/sotavento34/media/def1_zps77lv6hyu.png.html][IMG]http://i1249.photobucket.com/albums/hh505/sotavento34/def1_zps77lv6hyu.png[/IMG][/URL]